# Enable/disable Shiny widget based on values of 2 other Widgets

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I want to enable/disable a `Shiny widget` based on the values of 2 other `widgets` as below -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),

      prettyCheckbox(inputId = "Check1", label = "A"),
      prettyCheckbox(inputId = "Check2", label = "B"),
      uiOutput("Date_UI")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {



      output$Date_UI = 
        renderUI(dateInput(inputId = "Date", 
                            label = NULL, 
                            width = "80%",
                            value = Sys.Date(), 
                            min = Sys.Date() - 10, 
                            max = Sys.Date() + 10) 
              )

      observeEvent(c( 
            input$Check1,
            input$Check2
            ), 
            {
              if (input$Check1 || input$Check2) {
                  enable('Date')
                } else {
                  disable('Date')
                }
            })


    }
  )
```

With this I want that, if either of `Check1` and `Check2` is clicked then `Date` will be enabled. So if both were unselected then `Date` will be disabled. `GUI` should start with `Date` disabled.

Clearly this is not happening with above code? Can you please help to point what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code seems to work except for the initial loading of the app. Wrap the dateInput call in server with [disabled()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyjs/versions/1.1/topics/disabled) (shinyjs function) to have it initially disabled upon load:

```
output$Date_UI = 
      renderUI(disabled(dateInput(inputId = "Date", 
                         label = NULL, 
                         width = "80%",
                         value = Sys.Date(), 
                         min = Sys.Date() - 10, 
                         max = Sys.Date() + 10))
```